# How can I detect whether a type is a visible base of another type?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

If I do

```
struct A{};
struct C:private A{};

typedef char (&yes)[1];
typedef char (&no)[2];

template <typename B, typename D>
struct Host
{
 operator B*() const;
 operator D*();
};

template <typename B, typename D>
struct is_base_of
{
template <typename T> 
static yes check(D*, T);
static no check(B*, int);

static const bool value = sizeof(check(Host<B,D>(), int())) == sizeof(yes);
};

int main(){
 std::cout<<is_base_of<A,C>::value<<std::endl;
}
```

I get a 1. I would like to get a 0 when `C` is a private `A`, and a 1 when `C` is a public `A`.

[the code is derived from [How does `is_base_of` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910979/how-is-base-of-works) ]

Comment: A little off-topic, but can you really offer a bounty of X if your reputation is less than X?

Comment: I deleted my answer that says basically, "you cant" with templates, and an alternative to templates that could do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have access to a compiler with C++11 support?

If so, you can combine Chad's use of `static_cast` with `decltype` to create a very simple type trait implementation (as demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530928/checking-a-member-exists-possibly-in-a-base-class-c11-version)).  As per Jonathan Wakely's suggestion, the references have been replaced with pointers to avoid false positives when `D` defines an `operator B&()`.

```
template<typename> struct AnyReturn { typedef void type; };

template<typename B, typename D, typename Sfinae = void>
struct is_base_of: std::false_type {};

template<typename B, typename D>
struct is_base_of<B, D,
    typename AnyReturn< decltype( static_cast<B*>( std::declval<D*>() ) ) >::type
>: std::true_type {};
```

When using gcc 4.7:

```
struct Base {};
struct PublicDerived  : public  Base {};
struct PrivateDerived : private Base {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_base_of<Base, PublicDerived >::value << std::endl; // prints 1
    std::cout << is_base_of<Base, PrivateDerived>::value << std::endl; // prints 0
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but `is_base_of<A,B>` gives the wrong result if `B` has `operator A&()` i.e. conversion to `A`.  That can be solved by changing it to convert pointers instead i.e. `static_cast<B*>( std::declval<D*>() )`

Comment: This works with gcc 4.6.3 as well, but gcc 4.5.1 fails to compile for `PrivateDerived`: `error: 'Base' is an inaccessible base of 'PrivateDerived'`. I've had zero luck trying to get this (or any variant of this) to work in VS 2010.  It appears that it cannot handle the combination of `decltype` and `static_cast` in templates, potentially producing the wrong result or even crashing the compiler. I won't be able to check VS 2011 as it doesn't support XP.

Comment: Assuming the behavior in this answer is based on [DR339](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2634.html), this is supported in [GCC 4.4 and later](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), as well as [Clang 2.9 and later](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx0x), but not in [VC10 or VC11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx).  However, it is not required that access checking is part of the substitution process, which is why it fails when using GCC 4.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something that can be evaluated at runtime, or will a simple compile time error suffice?

```
struct A {};
struct B : private A {};

int main()
{
   B b;

   // gives error C2243: 'static_cast' : conversion from 'B *' to 'A &' exists, but is inaccessible
   A& a = static_cast<A&>(b);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you,but I need it the value at compile time, not an error, in order to set a template. Imagine template <class C,bool b=is_base_of<A,C>::value> struct x{};

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply the compile-time overload resolution trick to detect access specifiers, you would at least need that access specifiers are considered at the time overload resolution is done. This is not the case with **C++03**, so it cannot be done. I believe **C++11** changes this so with some artificial conversions and *SFINAE* you would be able to implement it.

**Update:** I'm going over *n3242* Overload Resolution section, and I cannot find anything that would indicate that access specifiers are considered for overload resultion at C++11.